# How to create .ipa file in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app. I can create the *.apk* file for Android by right-clicking on project and then click on *Archive*. I wonder how to generate the *.ipa* file for iOS using Visual Studio. If I right click on my iOS project, the *Archive* option is present, but it is disabled. I followed a few articles on this issue in few I found that connect to macOS on the remote. I don't want to run my project, only I need to generate the *.ipa* file which I will install on my iPhone. Please help me

Comment: Well you need a mac for that as well, Apple iOS is closed source and cannot be bundled without a MAC and provisioning, certificate creation.

Answer (score 0):

There are detailed steps in Official document about how to create a `.ipa` file in Visual Studio 2017:

Read this document will help: [creating-an-ipa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows#creating-an-ipa)

And here are documents about app-distribution: [app-distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/)

Answer (score -1):

By assuming you've done all  provisioning and mac connection(if don't see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows) article).

1. Set project configuration to `Ad-Hoc` or `AppStore`
2. Select `iOS` project as **Startup Project**
3. Right click and **Build** `iOS` project
4. At the end you'll have `.ipa` file in build folder(`{project location}/{project}.iOS/bin/Ad-Hoc/yourAppName.ipa`)

Comment: While this would not justify writing an answer on its own, I would like to add, that you can click on the iOS project in VS and select *"Show IPA file on build server"*, which will open Finder with the IPA file selected.

Comment: Plus: If your Device is in your Development profile, you do not need Ad-Hoc or AppStore profile. Release should be sufficient.